# How to grab individual vertex in UV editor?

Tags: uv, vertices, uv-image-editor

I want to align a line of vertices in a UV map of an object I am modeling, but whenever I try it moves all other vertices connected to them. How do I just select a single vertex while UV modeling?

Selecting a vertex (in this case, two vertices overlapping, but the same applies when I select one)
[image: Selecting a vertex (in this case, two vertices overlapping, but the same applies when I select one)]

It selects a vertex (or vertices) that are connected even though I didn't select them
[image: It selects a vertex (or vertices) that are connected even though I didn't select them]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable “Sticky Selection” mode in the dropdown menu to the right of the vertex/edge/face select boxes[image]

Comment: Hello :). Could you please add a screenshot? Can't find that option in my Blender. Thanks :).

Comment: Picture added. Note that this is in the UV editor window